Why "do not avenge" applies to "[all] members of your people" but "love" only to "thy neighbor"?
In Lev 19:18:

לֹא־תִקֹּם וְלֹא־תִטֹּר אֶת־בְּנֵי עַמֶּךָ וְאָהַבְתָּ לְרֵעֲךָ כָּמוֹךָ אֲנִי יְהוָה׃
You shall not take vengeance or bear a grudge against members of your people.
Love your fellow as yourself.

Why does "do not avenge or bear a grudge" apply to "[all] members of your people" but "love" (and many others) only to "thy neighbor/fellow"? Are there any Halachic implications, compared, for example, to the prohibition of "hating your brother"?

Some say רעך is supposed to include all people.

Just my own idea, but seems pretty simple. When you love them, they become your "neighbor". Otherwise, they are simply your "fellow national", to whom you should not bear ill will towards.

@RabbiKaii If it said "ואהבת את רעך כמוך" would you notice?

@AlBerko ? please spell out your point as I don't get it

@RabbiKaii Sure, when claiming a =>b it is not enough to show that a=>b but needs to show also that -b=>-a. So when arguing for a specific reason, one must ask, if NOT the formula in the verse, couldn't we reach the same conclusion? So imagine having two scrolls, one saying לרעך and one את רעך which one is the true scroll? If your hypothesis is right you must be able to falsify the other.

Rashi says your neighbor refers to Hashem

The word רֵעֲךָ/neighbor is not exclusive to the mitzvah of loving one's neighbor. It is also used in many different mitzvos including 10 commandments: Shemos 20:13, Shemos 20:14, Devarim 5:17, Devarim 5:18. Also commandments  Vayikra 19:13, Vayikra 19:16, and many other places. In particular, when Dathan and Aviram were fighting Shemos 2:13:
וַיֵּצֵא֙ בַּיֹּ֣ום הַשֵּׁנִ֔י וְהִנֵּ֛ה שְׁנֵֽי־אֲנָשִׁ֥ים עִבְרִ֖ים נִצִּ֑ים וַיֹּ֨אמֶר֙ לָֽרָשָׁ֔ע לָ֥מָּה תַכֶּ֖ה רֵעֶֽךָ׃
Moshe is using the word רֵעֲךָ when rebuking one of them. The reason is that the word רֵעַ means one who has something in common with another, often a bond of friendship (Artscroll Rashi commentary). Hence, Rashi comments: "THY FELLOW" (the word denotes one who is the equal of another) — who is as wicked as yourself (Exodus Rabbah 1:29). Because the word is used in 10 commandments, it means that all Jews became רֵעִים.
Additionally, I think, loving the ones who are closest, like neighbors, parents, siblings, spouses, is harder, because that is where the relationship can get tested for real. When dealing with people who stay far, issues that are mentioned in the above negative mitzvos are much less likely to arise due to distance.
The positive mitzvah to love one's neigbor, Sefer haChinuch 243 is also formulated in the negative:  (Shabbat 31a), “What is hateful to you, do not do to your fellow.” And they said in Sifra, Kedoshim, Chapter 4:12, “Rabbi Akiva said, ‘This is a great principle in the Torah’” — meaning to say that many commandments are dependent upon it. As one that loves his fellow like himself will not steal from him, will not have adultery with his wife, will not cheat him of goods or oppress him with words, will not move his boundary, and will not harm him in any way. So are many other religious duties bound up with it; the matter is evident to every understanding person. (translation of R. Elchanan (Charles) Wengrow). It means that at the bare minimum one has to fulfil all negative precepts bein adam l'chaveiro, which necessarily include רֵעֶֽךָ as the most likely chaveiro. Without רֵעֶֽךָ one could make a case that loving permits violating the above negative mitzvos.
The point is even strenthened with the fact that taking vengeance and grudge is formulated in plural, while loving the neighbor in the sigular. Revenging or bearing grudges or any other negative action is usually decided based on a limited number of bad character traits and can easily be extended to several people lacking such good qualities. At the same time, loving at the minimum is abstaining from all prohibitions bein adam l'chaveiro. Since some of the negative commandments are also formulated in the singular רֵעֲךָ, even at the minimum, we must have such personal conditioning when loving another Jewish person.

Thank you. רע is a very common expression, as well as a fellow (עמיתך) or a brother (אחיך). The difference is that בני עמך refers to ALL Jews (plural) while רעך is picky. Compare ואהבת לכל בני עמך.  Your answer seems to miss that point.

Ok, you could have told me that the paragraph before the last was not sufficient. That's why I added the last big one.

Thanks again, can your answer be boiled down to "Because the word is used in 10 commandments, it means that all Jews became רֵעִים." and, I add, therefore the two expressions are equivalent?

@AlBerko that was my 1st answer it defines רֵעֶֽךָ as any Jew because of 10 commandments. My 2nd answer accepts the meaning of רֵעֶֽךָ = neighbor and is based on Sefer haChinuch (if you take the overlap of the formulations of negative mitzvos distance-wise).

Wait, do you understand the difference between "[all] your people" and "your fellow" or the two are identical to you?

@AlBerko I finally addressed this point in the last paragraph.
